# How to debug "SurfaceFlinger GPU Deadline missed" Jank in Android 13 using perfetto

Tags: android, performance, surfaceflinger, perfetto, jank

[image]

The above sample image shows a perfetto systrace capture from Android 11 device. It shows GPU completion process in the SurfaceFlinger.

I'm facing a Jank (GPU Deadline missed) on Android 13 device, during this time the **GPU completion** process exceeded the 16milli sec timeline which is suspected to be the cause.

But how to debug further. Like why GPU deadline missed? is it due to any load? or low system/GPU configuration? Android AGI tool does not support this device. please suggest on how to debug to find the root cause or is there any useful materials on this topics.